# Implementation of ACL manager for JMultiplehotelreservation extension

Tags: joomla

I need to implement ACL manager feature for JMultiplehotelreservation  extension as I need to manage access levels for user to restrict access levels for features for hotel reservation extension according to user level.I need to verify compatability of hotel reservation extension with ACL manager extension for joomla 2.5

**URL for ACL manager extension** :
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/backend-a-full-access-control/17951

**URL for hotel reservation extension** : http://www.cmsjunkie.com/joomla_multi_hotel_reservation_standard

Looking forward for best solution

Comment: great, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: ACL manager is paid extension and I need to verify its compatibility with Hotel reservation extension and accordingly I can opt ACL manager for purchase

Comment: in which case, do you not think it would be better to contact the developer of ACL Manager to ask them it it's compatible? They will be able to give you an instant and more accurate answer

Comment: You don't need an extension to use ACL, the extension just makes a unified interface. Your question makes it sound like you have not looked at the core feature or read the websites of either extension developer thoroughly.